# Ignore failure of post build step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins job with summary plugin step in post build actions. Sometimes it fails because of absence of the necessary file for it(for some branches, and there is no ability to update them nearest time). Is it possible to ignore failure only in post build steps and mark build green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution - in build steps add shell step with command "touch summaryName.xml". If file exists it won't be changed. And if there is no summary file it will be created

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can ignore the failure by ticking **the check box [Do not fail this build if archiving returns nothing]** in advanced section.

Comment: It seems that we are talking about different plugins. I'm using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin#SummaryDisplayPlugin-Usage

Comment: Its the same plugin. You have to click on the **advanced** button to see the options.

Comment: In new version of this plugin there is no advanced button(